# Azure APIM: How to update apiRevision of an Api and set it to Current while deploying it through Bicep?

Tags: azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-bicep, apim

I need to deploy an API to APIM, update its revision and make it current.  I am looking for best practices to do this (i.e., updating an api), and to achieve it using Azure DevOps. Also, I have below questions,

1. My backing API service (Azure function) is a .Net application that has OpenAPI Specification defined using `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi`.  The versioning of the API is defined using `OpenApiInfo.Version` attribute.  For updating the specification i am using Bicep shown below,

> ```
> resource api 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis@2022-09-01-preview' = {
>   parent: apimInstance
>   name: '${apiName};rev=${apiRevision}'
>   properties: {
>     displayName: apiDisplayName
>     apiType: 'http'
>     format: 'openapi+json-link'
>     value: 'https://$(FunctionAppName).azurewebsites.net/api/swagger.json'
>     path: apiUrlSuffix
>     protocols: [
>       'https'
>     ]
>     subscriptionRequired: true
>     // isCurrent: makeCurrent
>     apiVersionSetId: apiVersionSet.id
>     apiVersion: apiVersionValue
>     apiRevision: apiRevisionValue
>   }
> }
> ```

**Question**: Can't the bicep (ARM) use the version information defined in the swagger.json file?  Currently, I am explicitly passing apiVersionValue.

2. In the above bicep, uncommenting the isCurrent results in failure of pipeline with "Cannot update revision ..." error.  How to update the apiRevision and set it to current?

Answer (score 0):

1- You can't do it with out-of-the-box `openapi+json-link` format as far as I can tell, maybe you can create a powershell script which downloads the spec, picks up the version and passes it as a param to your bicep

2- You can create a powershell script after creating the revision and set it as current

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$apimResopurceGroup,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$apimService,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$apiId,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$apiRevisionId
)

az apim api release create `
    --resource-group $apimResourceGroup `
    --api-id $apiId `
    --api-revision $apiRevisionId `
    --service-name $apimService `
    --notes "Releasing $apiRevisionId"
```